# SQL Server GMT date & time conversion hourly report using group by

Tags: sql-server, group-by, case, gmt

I have been beating my head on this problem for days now and would love some feedback or suggestions on how to properly handle this problem.

I am trying to create a SQL query that is run hourly that selects all records for the previous hour and inserts them into a new reports table. My current SQL query works as intended; but I now need to find out how to adjust the `CreationHour` and `CreationDate` based on the customers GMT setting.

The problem is that the Payment records are inserted based on the servers date / time (which is GMT -5 and datatype `datetime`) so I need to somehow adjust the time based on the customers GMT, and then add or subtract the -5 GMT of the server.

So far the only thing I can think of is using a CASE statement but the problem with this is that I will need to to use the same CASE statement 5 times, which will have 73 possible WHEN statements.

Can anyone suggest a better option on how to approach this or resolve this problem? So far over the last week I have run into 3 deadends and cannot find a more optimal way of approaching this.

Here is the current SQL query I am executing:

```
SELECT 
   P.ComputerID, P.CustomerID, MAX(C.GMT) AS TimeAdguest,
   MAX(DATEPART(HOUR, dateadd(hour, (C.GMT -1), P.CreationDateTime))) AS [CreationHour], 
   Convert(varchar(10),MAX(dateadd(hour, (C.GMT -1),P.CreationDateTime)),101) AS [CreationDate],
   SUM(P.SecondsPurchased) AS [Seconds],
   SUM(P.PagesPurchased) AS [Pages], 
   SUM(P.Amount) AS [Amount]
FROM [Payments] P
left Join Customer C ON C.CustomerID = P.CustomerID
WHERE 
    DATEPART(HOUR, P.CreationDateTime) = DATEPART(HOUR, dateadd(hour,-1, getdate()))
    AND Convert(varchar(10), dateadd(hour, -1, P.CreationDateTime), 101) = Convert(varchar(10), dateadd(hour, -1, getdate()), 101)
GROUP BY 
    Convert(varchar(10),P.CreationDateTime,101), P.ComputerID, P.CustomerID
```

And returns the following results:

```
ComputerID  CustomerID  TimeAdguest CreationHour    CreationDate    Seconds Pages   Amount
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 7679   1188    -2  8   03/27/2013  1670    0   56.9600009918213
12891   42  17  3   03/28/2013  740 0   26.7200005054474
12893   42  17  3   03/28/2013  480 0   20.1400001049042
12894   42  17  3   03/28/2013  280 0   10.8799998760223
12943   42  17  3   03/28/2013  120 0   1
12943   1188    -2  8   03/27/2013  240 0   2
13407   1188    -2  8   03/27/2013  960 0   40.2800002098084
13476   1188    -2  8   03/27/2013  840 0   25.6999996900558
14281   42  17  3   03/28/2013  562 0   6
16026   1188    -2  8   03/27/2013  1134    0   13
```

Answer (score 0):

The SQL below has a been simplified by removing the calculation of the hour being reported on i.e. I've assumed you want to report on payments between datetime's @t1 to @t2 (local server time). CreationHour and CreationDate are P.CreationDateTime adjusted to customers time-zone by adding 5 hours (to get time in GMT) and then adding offset of customers time-zone relative to GMT.

```
SELECT P.ComputerID, P.CustomerID,
HOUR(DATEADD(HOUR, 5 + C.GMT, P.CreationDateTime)) AS [CreationHour],
CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),DATEADD(HOUR, 5 + C.GMT, P.CreationDateTime),101) AS [CreationDate],
SUM(P.SecondsPurchased) AS [Seconds],
SUM(P.PagesPurchased) AS [Pages], 
SUM(P.Amount) AS [Amount]
FROM [Payments] P
INNER JOIN Customer C ON C.CustomerID = P.CustomerID
WHERE P.CreationDateTime BETWEEN @t1 AND @t2
GROUP BY P.ComputerID, P.CustomerID,
HOUR(DATEADD(HOUR, 5 + C.GMT, P.CreationDateTime))
CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),DATEADD(HOUR, 5 + C.GMT, P.CreationDateTime),101)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response Bob.  I will try the simplified code you posted and see how that works.  The problem with your fix for the GMT problem ( HOUR(DATEADD(HOUR, 5 + C.GMT, P.CreationDateTime))  ) though is since our server is +5 hours and if the customer was +10 GMT it would give a GMT of +15, when it should be 5.  Or if they were GMT +1 it would give +6 when it should be -4.

Comment: Your response did give me an idea on how to resolve this problem.  The record C.GMT is a numeric value assigned programitcally on a settings page, and is set again programatically.  What I can do is create a GMT table with these numeric values to the GMT time adjustment value, and simply join this table in the query.  I could then go left join GMT on C.GMT = G.GMTID  and then adjust the time using this value (HOUR(DATEADD(HOUR, 5 + G.GMTAdjust, P.CreationDateTime)) ).  I think that may be the best option other then changing the pages where customers set their GMT from a drop down.

Comment: I'd assumed C.GMT was the offset in hours from GMT. If not then what is C.GMT? You said in the question that the server was GMT-5, in which case for a customer with GMT +10 adding 15 hours is correct. Now you say the server if GMT+5 in which case change 5 for -5 in my sql above.